# gstreamer rtpvp8depay cannot decode stream

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, vp8

I have two GStreamer instances : a sender and a receiver. I want to stream RTP / VP8 video. It works perfectly fine if I stream via UDP, like this :

### sender

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v videotestsrc ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001
```

### receiver

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=9001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01, payload=(int)96" ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

That works fine. But when I try to stream throug a FIFO / named pipe (done with mkfifo()) with :

### sender

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v videotestsrc ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! filesink location = myPipe
```

### receiver

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location = myPipe ! capsfilter caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01, payload=(int)96 ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

It fails and my receiver continusouly outputs :

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVP8Depay:rtpvp8depay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstbasertpdepayload.c(387): gst_base_rtp_depayload_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVP8Depay:rtpvp8depay0:
Received invalid RTP payload, dropping
```

I think I read somewhere (but can't find it again) that it was because when using UDP, the RTP packets were separated properly, while using a named pipe like this, the packets being written are "chained" (**not** properly separated) and thus gstreamer doesn't know how much bytes to read to get a RTP packet.

Is this correct, and if yes, how can I change that ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.

I did not manage the byte-stream thing through a pipe, but I managed to use an `AppSrc` to feed the gst pipeline.

So my whole pipeline (might be useful for other people) looks like this : `appsrc -> rtpvp8depay -> vp8dec -> videoconvert -> videoscale -> appsink` (I'm using Gstreamer1.0 on ArchLinux).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

When going through a named pipe, the RTP are not packetized properly. You could either,

1. Send the encoded stream directly through as a byte-stream, without using the rtpvp8pay element.
2. Use another RTP element in GStreamer that handles byte-stream format, such as rtpstreampay or rtpgdppay. (I believe the rtpstreampay might be a GStreamer 1.0 element though.)

Comment: thanks for explaining why this fails. I'm going to try these right now, but I don't understand why this would work with bytestream : isn't there event less information about the format ? Aren't they just raw bytes ?
Besides, my two GSTreamer instances is just for test, my real application doesn't use GStreamer as a sender : the packets come from Janus Gateway, and they *are* RTP / VP8 encoded. I'm using GStreamer to depacketize RTP and decode VP8 to send the data to OpenCV. So does the raw bytestream thing still apply ?
Thanks a lot for answering !

Comment: If the incoming stream are RTP packetized streams, then you will need a RTP depacketizer (and probably a jitter buffer to handle network conditions) before the decoding and the byte-stream won't apply. I might be wrong but I believe named pipe is sending byte-streams, which is raw bytes and would chop the RTP packets at the wrong places, hence you are getting invalid RTP payloads.